# Manifolds and Riemannian geometry with a bundle viewpoint

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, holonomy

I was wondering if there are any books that builds the theory on manifolds and Riemannian geometry, but at the same time treats these subjects in the general case of bundles (similar to Jeffery Lee's book). Most of the books on Riemannian geometry that I'm aware of, only discuss the theory on Riemannian manifolds. I'm interested in books or even lecture notes that do this in a higher point of view. For example one can define connections on vector/principal bundles and discuss their curvature and the relation they have with the holonomy group of that curvature, when discussing geodesics, considering geodesic sprays, etc.

I was previously learning these material from amazing notes by Dr. Will J Merry. Unfortunately, they are not available any more. So, I have to switch to some other notes. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf

Comment: Dear Dr. Michor, I can't thank you enough. This is exactly what I was looking for! I also just checked your other notes and books afterwards; They are all amazing. Thanks a lot for sharing math openly. It's very kind.